# Can I pass an Intent extra on finish()?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm wondering, is it possible to send information to the activity that I return to after calling finish()?

For example, I have an Activity `SendMessageActivity.class` which allows the user to post a message to their feed. Once that message has been saved to the server, I call `finish()`. Should I instead just start my `MainActivity.class` with a new Intent? Or is it better for life cycle development to just finish `SendMessageActivity.class`?

I don't see the point of starting a new activity since closing the current one will always bring you back to `MainActivity.class`. How can I just send a String extra after finishing the current Activity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **onActivityResult**.

This might help you to understand **onActivityResult**.

By using `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)` you can **start** another Activity and then **receive a result** from that Activity in the `onActivityResult()` method.So `onActivityResult()` is from where you start the another Activity.

`onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` check the params here. request code is there to filter from where you got the result. so you can identify different data using their requestCodes!

**Example**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        // Use a unique request code for each use case 
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE = 0x9988; 

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Create an Intent to start AnotherActivity
            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);

            // Start AnotherActivity with the request code
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE);
        }

        //-------- When a result is returned from another Activity onActivityResult is called.--------- //
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // First we need to check if the requestCode matches the one we used.
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EXAMPLE) {

                // The resultCode is set by the AnotherActivity
                // By convention RESULT_OK means that what ever
                // AnotherActivity did was successful
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Get the result from the returned Intent
                    final String result = data.getStringExtra(AnotherActivity.EXTRA_DATA);

                    // Use the data - in this case, display it in a Toast.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Result: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // AnotherActivity was not successful. No data to retrieve.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`AnotherActivity`  <- This the the one we use to send data to `MainActivity`

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

        // Constant used to identify data sent between Activities.
        public static final String EXTRA_DATA = "EXTRA_DATA";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

            final View button = findViewById(R.id.button);
            // When this button is clicked we want to return a result
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Create a new Intent as container for the result
                    final Intent data = new Intent();

                    // Add the required data to be returned to the MainActivity
                    data.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, "Some interesting data!");

                    // Set the resultCode to Activity.RESULT_OK to 
                    // indicate a success and attach the Intent
                    // which contains our result data
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data); 

                    // With finish() we close the AnotherActivity to 
                    // return to MainActivity
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // When the user hits the back button set the resultCode 
            // to Activity.RESULT_CANCELED to indicate a failure
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

**Note** : Now check in `MainActivity` you `startActivityForResult` there you specify a `REQUEST_CODE`. Let's say you want to call three different Activities to get results.. so there are three `startActivityForResult` calls with three different **REQUEST_CODE**'s. REQUEST_CODE is nothing but a unique key you specify in your activity to uniquely identify your `startActivityForResult` calls.

Once you receive data from those Activities you can check what is the REQUEST_CODE, then you know ah ha this result is from this Activity.

It's like you send  mails to your lovers with a colorful covers and ask them to reply in the same covers. Then if you get a letter back from them, you know who sent that one for you. awww ;)

Comment: Is there an onActivityResult() function equivalent for the child activity? I'd assume it'd be called something like onActivityRequest() and it would allow me to take certain actions given what request code was called to start the activity.

Answer (score 3):

You can [set result](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) of an activity, which allow you to data into an initent.

In your first activity, call the new one with [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) and retrieve data in method onActivityResult. Everything is in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

in First Activity:

```
Intent first = new Intent(ActivityA,this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(first, 1);
```

Now in Second activity: set Result during `finish`()

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("result",result); //pass intent extra here
   setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);     
    finish();
```

First activity Catch the result;

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
   {  
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
      // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 1  
       if(requestCode==1)  
             {  
                String message=data.getStringExtra("result");   
                //get the result
             }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call finish() to avoid that the user go back to SendMessageActivity.class, you can set this flags to your intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This will open the MainActivity and remove the SendMessageActivity from the activities stack.